# Drop Down width is not working in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am using a drop down where the `<option>` width seem correct in Firefox, but not in Google Chrome.

Below is the example code.

```html
<select id="Select1" style="width:170px;" >
   <option></option>
   <option>how are you</option>
   <option>how are youhow are you</option>
   <option>how are youhow are youhow are you</option>
   <option>how are youhow are youhow are youhow are you</option>
   <option>how are youhow are youhow are youhow are youhow are you</option>
</select>
```

**What I want:**  I want that the `<option>` width to be the same in Firefox and Google Chrome.

Comment: It's unclear what behaviour you are expecting / experiencing differently between different browsers. In Chrome & Firefox just from the code in your question I [see identical results](https://jsfiddle.net/gzchochx/).

Comment: They don't look identical. Firefox keeps the space for the arrow on the option elements, chrome doesn't. Please see this screenshot http://screencast.com/t/DXhNriOSt

Comment: when i apply the above css on the above mentioned code so the drop down options width is decreased in fire fox but not in google chrome

Comment: are bootstrap dropdowns  allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't style webkit browsers `option` tag.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-optgroup-option-css-chrome/

Comment: i tried this but it is also not working for chrome the options values width is still not decreased

Comment: You **can't** style those in the way you want. If you really need that much control, Create your own drop down menu with `ul`, `li`, and javascript.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to fix the compatibility issues between fire fox and google chrome